# Symfony 6 order entity by relation entity property

Tags: sorting, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

I am pretty new on Symfony and i didn't find or understand how to manage my issue.

I am using Symfony 6, php 8 and knppaginator to display a CRUD.

I have a Country entity which have an id and a name

```
class Country {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'country', targetEntity: Shop::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    #[ORM\OrderBy(['name' => 'ASC'])]
    private Collection $shops;
```

and a Shop entity which have an id, name and a relation manyToOne with the Country entity

```
class Shop{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'shops')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private Country $country;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    private string $name;
```

On my Shop index page i display a simple table id|shop name|country name.

I am able to sort on these fields with kpnpaginator but the country field is sorted by id.

```
    public function index(ShopRepository $shopRepository, PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request): Response
{
    $shops = $paginator->paginate(
        $shopRepository->findAll(),
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        10
    );

    return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
        'shops' => $shops ,
    ]);
}
```

How can i sort this field by country name ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed an important piece of code, where you define the order in your controller or are you only using the `OrderBy` attribute?  If that's the case, I believe you mixed up the location of the `OrderBy` attribute.

The `OrderBy` attribute is on the `Country.Shops` property, which should order the Shops relation by name when querying the Countries.  If you want to sort the Countries by name when querying shops, you should put the `OrderBy` attribute on `Shops.country` instead.

The most important question here is if you really want to do it this way, since this will become the default for all your queries. Also your query `$shopRepository->findAll()` will become very slow if there are a lot of records to paginate, since it will load all shops in memory and paginate of that data. Instead of returning a `QueryBuilder` object which KpnPaginatorBundle should understand and only query what is required to display.

Also in my opinion you should build this logic inside your Controller instead of using the Doctrine Attributes for this. Alltough this doesn't impact the functionality of your pagination.

For example, if you remove the `OrderBy` attribute since you don't know what is was used for anymore in a few months, the functionality of your pagination now changes. But if you're fine with that, leave it.

Comment: Thx. Indeed i mixed things up. 
I prefer to manage the order in the controller.
I moved the OrderBy attribute but nothing changed.
I also changed the query with a custom query already ordered by country's name but it seems that knp paginate's method change the sort to country's id.
In my Shops CRUD  page, if i clicked on the field "Country", i'd like the countries are sort by name and not by id

Answer (score 0):

Normally with the OrderBy attribute you can sort your fields.Try to add this attribute to the parameter country in the Shop Entity.

#[ORM\OrderBy(["name"=>"DESC"])]
private Country $country;